# Session Expiration Warning

Tags: xpages

I have an XPages app that is supposed to save the main doc (and do a couple of other things) when the user clicks a button on the dialog box.  The dialog box is presented by a CSJS function which runs according to a setInterval command.  The dialog box and all the programming that present it are on a Custom Control.  I have no problem displaying the dialog box, but have been unable to come up with a way to save the underlying document.  I have other dialog boxes on their respective XPages, and saving the doc with a click (and some SSJS) works fine, but the same process doesn't seem to work if the dialog box is on a CC.  I have searched all over the web, including StackOverflow, and haven't been able to find just what I need.  Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Here's the code from one of my more recent attempts:

```
<xp:button value="Continue" id="button1">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false" id="eventHandler1">
    <xp:this.script>
        <![CDATA[
            if (intvlID2) {
                clearInterval(intvlID2);
            }

            var b18 = dojo.query('[id$="button18"]')[0];
            if (b18) {
                b18.click();
            } else {
                location.reload(true);
            }

            XSP.closeDialog('#{id:WarningDialog}');
        ]]>
    </xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

As you can see, it clears the interval first, then looks for a button on the underlying form.  I've been able to verify that it does, in fact, find the button, but nothing happens with the click() command.  The button it finds includes this save command that doesn't appear to execute:

```
document1.getDocument(true).save();
```

The button works perfectly when clicked by mouse or tapped by finger, but not when 'clicked' programmatically by another button on a CC.

Comment: Can you add your code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

The currentDocument global variable can be used to access the nearest dominoDocument datasource. Alternatively, the Extension Library dialog box has an additional parameter when closing the dialog box, the id of the refresh area. Maybe you can use that to trigger a save, something like setting a requestScope variable on close, and in the refresh area having code that does a save if the requestScope variable is set and, after save, clearing the requestScope variable?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Paul.  I will give them a try!